# bash: qmake: command not found

Tags: windows, qt, qmake

Добрый день, у меня возникла ошибка: `bash: qmake: command not found`. Когда я выполняю команду `qmake -r`. Я использую Windows 10 и так и не нашел нормальных инструкций что делать. У меня проект написан на С++ для Qt, я Qt скачивал с официального сайта, так что утилита qmake установлена.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверно так: `полный_путь_к_qmake -r`

Comment: Нет не получается:
Ivan@home-pc MINGW64 ~/merkaartor (master)
$ C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\winrt_x64_msvc2017\bin\qmake -r
bash: C:QtQt5.10.05.10.0winrt_x64_msvc2017binqmake: command not found

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, вы используете MSYS - пути нужно использовать в формате Unix: `cygpath "C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\winrt_x64_msvc2017\bin\qmake"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На время текущей сессии:

```
export PATH=<path-to-qmake-dir>:$PATH
which qmake
```

Только `<path-to-qmake-dir>` замените на путь к директории, в которой хранится qmake.

---

Вы используете MSYS - соответственно пути нужно использовать в формате Unix. Для быстрой конвертации:

```
cygpath "C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\winrt_x64_msvc2017\bin\qmake"
```

---

Вы используете Qt, собранный под MSVC, но судя по всему, собираете проект под MinGW - могут возникнуть проблемы

Comment: Что я делаю не так ?                                                             
Ivan@home-pc MINGW64 ~/merkaartor (master)
$ export PATH=<C:/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/winrt_x64_msvc2017/bin/qmake.exe>:$PATH
bash: :$PATH: ambiguous redirect

Ivan@home-pc MINGW64 ~/merkaartor (master)
$ qmake -r
bash: qmake: command not found

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, уберите угловые скобки

Comment: @IvanTriumphov обновил ответ

Comment: @Pavel Parshin - Спасибо за ответ . Но у меня много папок qmake ... как мне определить, до какой мне указывать путь ?

Comment: @Pavel Parshin попробовал добавить другой путь PATH=C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\mingw53_32\bin\qmake:$PATH ... но тоже самое  bash: qmake: command not found

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, в PATH должен быть путь к **папке** с qmake, а не самому qmake